# What were Goodkat's motives in saving Max's life in "Lucky Number Slevin"?

Tags: character, lucky-number-slevin

Throughout the movie, Goodkat's motives are unexplained and seemingly arbitrary.

He saves what appears to be a random boy's life for no apparent reason, helps him seek revenge twenty years later on upon old business partners while getting nothing in return, and warns Max he's going to try to kill Lindsey - then suddenly lets the two of them go without explanation.

What exactly were Goodkat's reasons to do all of this? The most I can think of is that he took pity on Max but I cannot fathom what would prompt a renowned hitman to do so, or what would lead him to consider assisting Max and then letting Max/Lindsey go.

Comment: Pity when Max's a child, and then like a "teacher/student" or "parent/child".

Answer (score 1):

He made a decision not to kill him, weather it was because he couldn't kill a child, grew a conscience or felt bad for a boy who just lost his family, it wasn't specified but probably a mixture of all those.

As for helping him getting his revenge, he raised the boy, so it was a natural thing to help someone he probably consider  his son.

The same with letting Lindsey go, he won't save a boy, raise him and help him avenge his family and then go a kill the one he fell in love with.

Comment: Then why even plan to kill her?

Comment: He didn't know that Slevin cared about her that much then. He knew that the moment he shot her and realized that they're trying to fake her death. He figured out that S is trying to save her and probably told her the truth. He could've killed her then but didn't/decided not to. The scene in the end he's just revealing that he knows and understands and it's ok.